How do I pass xcom to traditional operator from task created using @task decorator?
I'm trying to get my head around the TaskFlow API & XCom in airflow and am getting stuck, hoping someone here can help. I'm using EmrServerlessCreateApplicationOperator and I want to pass a value to it from another task which has been created using the @task decorator. My DAG definition is:
import datetime
from airflow.decorators import task, dag

from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.emr import EmrServerlessCreateApplicationOperator
    
@dag(
    dag_id="demo-xcom-problem",
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    catchup=False
)
def taskflow():
    @task(multiple_outputs=True)
    def config() -> dict:
        return {
            "name": "my-spark-app",
        }
    create_app_fails = EmrServerlessCreateApplicationOperator(
            task_id="create_spark_app_fails",
            job_type="SPARK",
            release_label="emr-6.9.0",
            config=config(),
            aws_conn_id="",
        )
    create_app_succeeds = EmrServerlessCreateApplicationOperator(
            task_id="create_spark_app_succeeds",
            job_type="SPARK",
            release_label="emr-6.9.0",
            config={
                "name": "my-spark-app",
            },
            aws_conn_id="",
        )
    create_app_fails
    create_app_succeeds
taskflow()


create_spp_succeeds successfully creates a app on EMR Serverless
create_app_fails does exactly the same thing as create_spark_app_succeeds except that it takes a parameter value from an upstream task. This one fails with error:


ERROR - Failed to execute job 730 for task create_spark_app_fails (botocore.client.ClientCreator._create_api_method.._api_call() argument after ** must be a mapping, not PlainXComArg; 2990)

From that error I'm. guessing that I'm not passing the value properly. But I can't figure out how to do it. Hoping someone here can tell me how to solve this.

The problem was that EmrServerlessCreateApplicationOperator could not (in the version I was using) accept templated values for the config parameter. I have blogged about a solution here: https://medium.com/@jamiekt/subclass-airflow-operators-to-make-parameters-templateable-b2b0ea64b39e
